# Turn a list, that is in another list, into a string, then reverse the string

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm new to programming in Python (and programming in general) and we were asked to develop a function to encrypt a string by rearranging the text. We were given this as a test:

```
encrypt('THE PRICE OF FREEDOM IS ETERNAL VIGILENCE', 5)
'SI MODEERF FO ECIRP EHT ECNELIGIV LANRETE'
```

We have to make sure it works for any string of any length though. I got as far as this before getting stuck:

```
##Define encrypt
def encrypt(text, encrypt_value):

##Split string into list

text_list = text.split()

##group text_list according to encrypt_value    

split_list = [text_list[index:index+encrypt_value] for index in xrange\
          (0, len(text_list), encrypt_value)]
```

If I printed the result now, this would give me:

```
encrypt("I got a jar of dirt and you don't HA", 3)
[['I', 'got', 'a'], ['jar', 'of', 'dirt'], ['and', 'you', "don't"], ['HA']]
```

So I need to combine each of the lists in the list into a string (which I think is ' '.join(text)?), reverse it with [::-1], before joining the whole thing together into one string. But how in the world do I do that?

Comment: You already have all the steps; why not experiment with them in the interpreter?

Comment: I've been experimenting for an hour... I just started programming last month, I barely know what I'm doing!

Answer (score 0):

To combine your elements, you can try to using reduce:

```
l = [['I', 'got', 'a'], ['jar', 'of', 'dirt'], ['and', 'you', "don't"], ['HA']]
str = reduce(lambda prev,cur: prev+' '+reduce(lambda subprev,word: subprev+' '+word,cur, ''), l, '')
```

It will result in:

```
"  I got a  jar of dirt  and you don't  HA"
```

If you want to remove extra spaces:

```
str.replace('  ',' ').strip()
```

This reduce use can be easily modified to reverse each sublist right before combining their elements:

```
str = reduce(lambda prev,cur: prev+' '+reduce(lambda subprev,word: subprev+' '+word,cur[::-1], ''), l, '')
```

Or to reverse the combined substrings just before joining all together:

```
str = reduce(lambda prev,cur: prev+' '+reduce(lambda subprev,word: subprev+' '+word,cur, '')[::-1], l, '')
```

Comment: I KNOW how to combine them. What I don't know is how to reverse each list separately BEFORE combining them. And the code needs to work for a string of any length with any encrypt_value too.

Comment: @SomeLameStuff Add 6 characters to the solution I did post and you will reverse each sublist before combining its elements with the other lists. I have edited my answer to do that.

Comment: Looking at the question, you _also_ need to reverse each sub-sub-list, i.e. string, before joining them, I think.

Comment: @bsink I just edited my answer to include that possibility too. reduce combinations are quite versatile. He can remove separation spaces, I put them for aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're looking for fairly simply with a few nested list comprehensions.

---

For example, you already have

```
split_list = [['I', 'got', 'a'], ['jar', 'of', 'dirt'], ['and', 'you', "don't"], ['HA']]
```

What you want now is to reverse each triplet of words with a list comprehension, e.g. like so:

```
reversed_sublists = [sublist[::-1] for sublist in split_list]
// [['a', 'got', 'I'], ['dirt', 'of', 'jar'], ["don't", 'you', 'and'], ['HA']]
```

Then reverse each string in each sublist

```
reversed_strings = [[substr[::-1] for substr in sublist] for sublist in split_list]
// [['a', 'tog', 'I'], ['trid', 'fo', 'raj'], ["t'nod", 'uoy', 'dna'], ['AH']]
```

And then join them all up, as you said, with ' '.join(), e.g.

```
' '.join([' '.join(sublist) for sublist in reversed_strings])
// "a tog I trid fo raj t'nod uoy dna AH"
```

---

**But** nothing says you can't just do all those things at the same time with some nesting:

```
' '.join([' '.join([substring[::-1] for substring in sublist[::-1]]) for sublist in split_list])
// "a tog I trid fo raj t'nod uoy dna AH"
```

I personally prefer the aesthetic of this (and the fact you don't need to go back to strip spaces), but I'm not sure whether it performs better than Pablo's solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = [['I', 'got', 'a'], ['jar', 'of', 'dirt'], ['and', 'you', "don't"], ['HA']]

print "".join([j[::-1]+' ' for i in b for j in reversed(i)])

a tog I trid fo raj t'nod uoy dna AH
```

Is this what you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are trying to do it in one list comprehension?
It's probably easier to conceptualize (and implement) by breaking it down into parts:

```
def encrypt(text, encrypt_value):
    reversed_words = [w[::-1] for w in text.split()]
    rearranged_words = reversed_words[encrypt_value:] + reversed_words[:encrypt_value]
    return ' '.join(rearranged_words[::-1])
```

Example output:

```
In [6]: encrypt('THE PRICE OF FREEDOM IS ETERNAL VIGILENCE', 5)
Out[6]: 'SI MODEERF FO ECIRP EHT ECNELIGIV LANRETE'
```